# What is correct: grades 7 to 12 students or grade 7 to 12 students?

Tags: grammar

When you are referring to a program for students in grades 7 to 12, do you write "grades 7 to 12 students" or "grade 7 to 12 students"?

Comment: They're are multiple grades, so use the plural.

Comment: @Clare It sounds better to me to call them the (not singular; unmarked?) *grade 7-12* students.

Answer (score 1):

I think "seventh to twelfth grade students" is much better and grammatically safer.
Or just "7th to 12th grade students".

Comment: Probably so - although common usage among secondary school educators who write is "students in grades 7-12," a usage no doubt born of a sensitivity to the implication that students might be labeled and thereby devalued somehow.

Comment: Be aware that in the US, we usually speak of 7th grade, although grade 7 is sometimes seen, and is readily understood.  But the reverse is true in other Anglophone countries, such as Canada and the UK.